# How can be OpenMP used with the class and Eigen?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, eigen

I am trying to make code using OpenMP, some class and Eigen.

The overall code is at the bottom.

The code is a simplified version of what I want to do in my project.

The simplified code is just a matrix inverse and multiplication using class and OpenMP.

If I don't use the OpenMP, I get the results of

```
 solution in for loop at 0th iteration is... 1 1 1
 solution in class at 0th iteration is... 1 1 1
 solution in for loop at 1th iteration is... 4 4 4
 solution in class at 1th iteration is... 4 4 4
 solution in for loop at 2th iteration is... 9 9 9
 solution in class at 2th iteration is... 9 9 9
 solution in for loop at 3th iteration is... 16 16 16
 solution in class at 3th iteration is... 16 16 16
```

However, If I use the OpenMP, I get the results of

```
 9   11 91  
 1
16 16
 solution in class at 3th iteration is... 116   16 161
 1 1
 solution in class at 2th iteration is... 1
9 9 9
 solution in for loop at 1th iteration is...  solution in for loop at 9 
13th iteration is... 1
 solution in class at 0th iteration is...  4 4  4 16 solution in for loop at 1 
 solution in for loop at  01 11 
1 solution in for loop at  1 solution in for loop at  41 3th iteration is... th iteration is... 
16 9  solution in for loop at th iteration is... 1 solution in class at 33th iteration is...  th iteration is... 161 
 16  solution in for loop at  016 16 2th iteration is... 1616   1616   16 161616th iteration is... 
 solution in for loop at 19  solution in class at 3th iteration is... 9 9
16
```

The results are corrupted.

Why does this happen?

Also, at first, I found that only using "#pragma omp parallel for" results in the error that occurs when LDLT is not initialized.

So, I added the following instead of "#pragma omp parallel for".

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(j,k) firstprivate(foo)
```

```
class Foo {
 private:
  std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>> a;
  Eigen::LDLT<Eigen::MatrixXd> Minv; // Minv
  std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>> b;
  std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>> solution;
 public:
  Foo() {};
  ~Foo() {};
  void Initialization() {
    a.resize(4);
    b.resize(4);
    solution.resize(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      a.at(i).setZero();
      b.at(i).setZero();
      solution.at(i).setZero();
    }
  }

  void SetInv(int idx) {
    a.at(idx) = (1.0/(idx+1.0))*Eigen::Matrix3d::Identity();
    b.at(idx) = (idx+1)*Eigen::Vector3d::Ones();
    Minv.compute(a.at(idx));
  }

  void Calculation(int idx) {
    solution.at(idx) = Minv.solve(b.at(idx));
  }

  Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1> &ReturnSolution(int idx) {
    return solution.at(idx);
  }

  void ShowSolution(int idx) {
    std::cout << " solution in class at " << idx << "th iteration is... "<< solution.at(idx).transpose() << std::endl;
  }

};
```

I hope to know what the corrupted result is made.

Comment: Generally please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. the code snippet should be compilable **and** runnable without any changes. Have you read [this page](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html) about using Eigen in a multithreaded context?

Comment: `cout` does not guarantee that the output is printed in a raw: there is generally no lock in it. You can use `printf` to get "uninterrupted" lines (AFAIK `printf` is guaranteed to be synchronized, typically using a lock internally). Multiple calls to `printf` can be "interrupted" though. In your case, you can also protect the `cout` call yourself with a *critical section*. Note there will be no order but if you need a specific order, then parallelism is certainly not what you need.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the results are corrupted, because using OpenMP you made a multithreaded code. There are several threads doing `cout` at the same time - therefore you can see the mess.

if you want to have clear output, you need implement a mutex to make your code thread safe. Simplified example:

```
#include <mutex>

std::mutex mtx;
#pragma omp parallel for private(j,k) firstprivate(foo)
{
    /* Your work happens here */
    { // use brackets to show scope where mutex is locked
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        std::cout << "Some result you want to print";
    }
}
```

And link to doc: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard

> Also, at first, I found that only using "#pragma omp parallel for"
> results in the error that occurs when LDLT is not initialized.

Please provide sample code with your implementation of `#pramgma omp...` so it will be easier to answer your question.

Comment: Mixing OpenMP with another threading mechanism is not covered by the OpenMP specification and the behaviour may be vendor-specific. The main advantage of OpenMP is that you don't have to change the code or deal with technical details. Simply add a `#pragma` directive before the `cout` line: `#pragma omp critical`.